# w3c DOM and getElementById

Tags: java, xml

I am using w3c DOM api in java . When I first parse my XML from an input stream and use `dom.getElementById("nodeId")` method , it works . But If I update my dom with some node element having ID attributes , and then tries to retrieve this node using `dom.getElementById("ID")`, then it doesn't work and return null.
Any Idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide your code and what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact the JavaDoc says something along the lines that getElementById returns the Element that has an ID attribute with the given value. **An attribute with the name "ID" or "id" is not of type ID unless it is so defined.**

How is an attribute defined as an ID attribute? With a DTD or schema. If you are not validating the XML, then the API is useless.

So, what to do if you want to find an element for which the attribute named "id" has a given value? Several options were offered in GetElementById Pitfalls. One of them is to use an XPath expression like this:`"//*[@id = 'myId']".`

Also, in the Apache XML Security project, the class `org.apache.xml.security.utils.IdResolve`r was specifically created to address this problem. Calling `IdResolver.getElementById(doc, id)` will return the element you are looking for.

referhttp://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/738/

here is an example to achieve it [Java: How to make getElementById() work using xml schema](http://blog.amitsharma.in/2008/05/java-how-to-make-getelementbyid-work.html)

Comment: Thanks Hamnet..but As I am saying I have made this working for me by using an XSD and now the problem is its working when I first parsed it but then for dynamically added nodes, its not working.

Comment: First I am creating some nodes using anyElement = domDoc.createElement(type); and then parentNode.appendChild(anyElement );

Comment: @Chandan its fine. but without looking towards code i can not guess whats going wrong.

Comment: @Hament,I have used the same sample "Java: How to make getElementById() work using xml schema" . It worked for me but not working for dynamically added node.If you can confirm that it will also work for dynamically added nodes as well, it will be great.

Comment: @Chandan have you written dynamically added element to file ?

Comment: yes, It is going into the file and upon loading the file, its also working...I think its an issue of specifying uniqueId in XSD..something is going wrong there...I have used Xpath anyways.Thanks for ur time.